# Jquery UI - Sortable[Portlet] - button double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've problem with Jquery UI - sortable component. 
Problem explanation:

- click on button1 -> result "alert"
- drag portlet contains button1 to another column and then click on button1 -> result "alert" "alert" (action represented by click function is triggerd twice per event)

Simple code (modification portlet example from Jquery UI webpage):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Portlets</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="../../jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.sortable.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../demos.css">
    <style>
    .column { width: 170px; float: left; padding-bottom: 100px; }
    .portlet { margin: 0 1em 1em 0; }
    .portlet-header { margin: 0.3em; padding-bottom: 4px; padding-left: 0.2em; }
    .portlet-header .ui-icon { float: right; }
    .portlet-content { padding: 0.4em; }
    .ui-sortable-placeholder { border: 1px dotted black; visibility: visible !important; height: 50px !important; }
    .ui-sortable-placeholder * { visibility: hidden; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".column" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".column"
        });

        $( ".portlet" ).addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
            .find( ".portlet-header" )
                .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
                .prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>")
                .end()
            .find( ".portlet-content" );

        $( ".portlet-header .ui-icon" ).click(function() {
            $( this ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick" ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-plusthick" );
            $( this ).parents( ".portlet:first" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
        });

        $( ".column" ).disableSelection();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="demo">

<div class="column">

    <div class="portlet">
        <div class="portlet-header">Feeds</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
        <div>
            <div id="button1"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
                                $( "#button1" ).button({
                                    icons: {
                                        primary: "ui-icon-locked"
                                    },
                                    label: 'Button1'
                                }).click(function(){
                                    alert('Alert');
                                });
        </script>
    </div>

    <div class="portlet">
        <div class="portlet-header">News</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="column">

    <div class="portlet">
        <div class="portlet-header">Shopping</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="column">

    <div class="portlet">
        <div class="portlet-header">Links</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>

    <div class="portlet">
        <div class="portlet-header">Images</div>
        <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
    </div>

</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->



<div class="demo-description">
<p>
    Enable portlets (styled divs) as sortables and use the <code>connectWith</code>
    option to allow sorting between columns.
</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you bind the click function to button1 in the html of the portlet itself, so it is probably executed a second time when jQuery UI clones a helper object. The solution is simple, just move the code inside the script element of your Feeds portlet into the script section in the head of the page (in the function body like the other code that is executed by the ready handler).